# Phonegap iOS build not showing background image

Tags: ios, css, uiwebview

I've been struggling with this for a couple of hours for now, I've tried every solution that could find on the web, but nothing works.

Here is the a css file:

```
body{
    background-image: url('/img/login-background-small.png');
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-position: 100% 100%;
}
```

On the livePreview in Chrome on Mac everything is showing well but when I build iOS app, simulation is not showing any image in the background.

I've tried different picture sizes, tried moving css files after and before html tag, tried removing leading / sign from image path, but nothing seems to help.

Is there an alternative way of setting background image?

Hope someone is able to help.

Comment: `background-position: 100% 100%;` would move the image to the outside edge of each bound wouldn't it? Try `background-position: 0px 0px;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `background-position: 0px 0px;`.
The setting you had now, placed the image in a way that the left top-corner appears in the bottom right corner.